# Laravel automatically Logout after few minutes

Tags: php, laravel

Two clones of my Laravel app, run on two servers and they are connected to one database server. The app is accessed via a load balancer.

However, the problem is that when the system is access via load balancer, the user is automatically logged out after 2-3 minutes.

**This does not happen** when the system is access through the direct IP of one of the servers.

The Session driver is set to Database.

So, what's the problem here ? I'm not sure what piece of code should I put here as your aid. I only use `.env` file to set configurations.

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Thanks!

Comment: just thinking about `SESSION_LIFETIME`. What is the value of that?

Comment: It's still the default value. 120. Which is 120 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the error. It was the App Key of the Laravel app. One Server's Laravel app key has been changed by mistake during the migration. That's the bug that causes automatic sign out and token mismatch error.

So, if anyone one setting up this kind of Server setup with Laravel app, make sure all the App Keys are same.

Hope this helps!